# C# Strongly typed dataset validation approach

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to "learn" C# and building my 1st database driven data entry application. I am coming from Oracle development, hence wondering whether am doing few things right, as most of the examples I could find are dealing with datasets derived using SQL

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace lSystem
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void l_PEOPLEBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if ((string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fIRST_NAMETextBox.Text) || (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cIVIL_IDTextBox.Text) ||
                (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tELEPHONE_NUMBERTextbox.Text)))))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error, one of the mandatory columns are not filled up");
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                this.Validate();
                this.pERSON_IDTextBox.Text = this.l_PEOPLETableAdapter.ScalarQuery().ToString();
                this.l_PEOPLEBindingSource.EndEdit();
                this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.uNUDataSet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception happened, original message: " + ex.Message);
            }

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'uNUDataSet.L_PEOPLE' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.l_PEOPLETableAdapter.Fill(this.uNUDataSet.L_PEOPLE);
           // this.fIRST_NAMETextBox.Focus();
            this.ActiveControl = this.fIRST_NAMETextBox;

        }

        private void sByName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.l_PEOPLETableAdapter.FillByNAME(this.uNUDataSet.L_PEOPLE, this.sByNameText.Text);
        }

        private void fIRST_NAMETextBox_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fIRST_NAMETextBox.Text))
            {
                eNROLL_errorprovider.SetError(fIRST_NAMETextBox, "Name required");
                fIRST_NAMETextBox.Focus();
            }
        }

        private void cIVIL_IDTextBox_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cIVIL_IDTextBox.Text))
            {
                eNROLL_errorprovider.SetError(cIVIL_IDTextBox, "Civil ID Number required");
                cIVIL_IDTextBox.Focus();
            }
        }

        private void tELEPHONE_NUMBERTextbox_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tELEPHONE_NUMBERTextbox.Text))
            {
                eNROLL_errorprovider.SetError(tELEPHONE_NUMBERTextbox, "Telephone Number required");
                tELEPHONE_NUMBERTextbox.Focus();
                }
            else
            {
                eNROLL_errorprovider.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do with the above piece of code is, unless the user enters first name, civil id number and supply the telephone number, the form shouldn't submit the data. For the person id, I am using a sequence, called through a scalar query attached to the table adaptor.

While I click the binding navigator save button, what should execute in order to fire the validation events attached with the text columns so that the error provider will get activated?

Comment: I think am getting closer with the following example [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-OchPW47Zbc)

Answer (score -1):

You need to register the event like the code below

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            tELEPHONE_NUMBERTextbox.Validated += new EventHandler(tELEPHONE_NUMBERTextbox_Validated);
        }

        private void tELEPHONE_NUMBERTextbox_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
```

Comment: it doesn't help. What I want to achieve is, while the save button pressed, all the cells those are attached with the error provider should be validated & stop the user from generating a new sequence for the person id cell.